# one() function of jQuery kills everything

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make an autocomplete list like Google does. When you type something it will suggest some words for you and when you press the <kbd>down</kbd> button the element you are on becomes blue.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sn9V8/) that shows the issue. Every time, when I press the <kbd>down</kbd> button, just one element must be blue but in here it doesn't work.

What's wrong in this code?

```
$(".search").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        var attr = $("#showlist").find("li").attr("style");
        if (typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false){
            var stylist = $("#showlist").find("[style]");
            stylist.removeAttr("style");
            stylist.next().attr("style","background-color:blue");
        } else {
            $("#showlist li:first-child").attr("style", "background-color:blue");
        }
    }
})
```

I have tried the `one("keydown", function() {})` instead of `keydown(function() {})` function of jQuery but it didn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

It's good to try to learn how to do this on your own, but since you tagged your question with jQuery, are you aware that there is a jQuery-UI plugin that handles autocomplete? It is quite robust and can handle JSON and such returned from Ajax.

Here's the [demo page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) for the plugin, and here's the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

For the sake of illustration, here is the code for the very simple example shown on that demo page. It populates the control from a hard-coded list, which may be unlikely IRL.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The key part in there is the exceedingly simple wiring up of the control:

```
 $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
```

Even if you elect not to use that plugin, you might get a good idea from reading the underlying code of how to do your autocomplete.

I will also note that it may be helpful to know as you are googling around, this functionality is also often referred to as "autosuggest".

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code is not working is because this line is corrupted.

```
var attr = $("#showlist").find("li").attr("style");
```

It can't work as find("li") will return an array with 4 li in it. You should add `[style]` to the selector to select only that with the style set.

My JSFiddle after fixing that line:
http://jsfiddle.net/Sn9V8/2/

Anyway, I would suggest you two things:

- Use classes instead of applying style's everytime. The code will look easier and simpler.
- Take a look at the plugins mentioned by the others. They have great docs and support from the community, so they will speed up your development.

Comment: Seems we were coming to the same conclusion at the same time :)

Comment: Haha, you are right :) It's good to see such a big "traffic" on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have, `var attr = $("#showlist").find("li").attr("style");`

`attr` will always be a jQuery object even if it doesn't find the element.  So in your next line `typeof attr !== 'undefined'` will always be true.

---

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sn9V8/7/) for a quick update to your issue.

```
$(".search").keydown(function (e) {

    // Up
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        var $active = $("#showlist li.active");

        if ($active.length){
            if ($active.prev('li').length)
               $active.removeClass('active').prev('li').addClass('active');
        }
        else 
            $("#showlist li:first-child").addClass('active');
    }

    // Down
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        var $active = $("#showlist li.active");

        if ($active.length){
            if ($active.next('li').length)
               $active.removeClass('active').next('li').addClass('active');
        }
        else 
            $("#showlist li:first-child").addClass('active');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather rely on classes for this instead of reading inline styles.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Sn9V8/9/)

```
var $items = $('#showlist li'),
    $selectedItem = $items.find('.selected'),
    lastIndex = $items.length - 1,
    selectedIndex = -1;

$(".search").keydown( function(e) {

    var key = e.which,
        down = key === 40;

    if (!down && key !== 38) return;

    selectedIndex += down? 1 : -1;

    if (selectedIndex < 0 || selectedIndex > lastIndex) 
        selectedIndex = down? 0 : lastIndex;

    $selectedItem.removeClass('selected');

    $selectedItem = $($items[selectedIndex]).addClass('selected');
});
```